# Follow-up: Javascript Syntax-Highlighter for Java

Tags: javascript, beginner, html, css, regex

**Background**

The basics of this project have already been discussed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245806/javascript-syntax-highlighter-for-java).

I've improved the following things:

[Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/245818/214772) mentioned that I shouldn't use multiple elements with the same id. I corrected that and use classes instead. I also removed units from `style.css` when the value is 0. Furthermore I removed `!important`.

Sᴀᴍ Onᴇᴌᴀ also pointed out, I did not follow always follow the common style-guide. I tried to improve it for this follow-up question.

---

[Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/245816/214772) mentioned that it is not possible to have html-tags in for example comments, without destroying the formatting.

I've solved this problem by replacing `&` and `<`:

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp("&", "g"), "&amp;");
text = text.replace(new RegExp("<", "g"), "&lt;");
```

---

[FeRD](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/245850/214772) noted, that inputs like `System.out.println("Hi \"friend\".");` cause problems because of the escaped quotes. For this problem i used the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10786066/13634030).

Another problem was to highlight `private Account my_import_export;`. This problem also was solved by changing the regex a bit.

---

[Charlie Harding](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245806/javascript-syntax-highlighter-for-java#comment483008_245806) mentioned in the comments that something like `serif (x)`, `if (x) y();` or `if(x) y()` is not possible. This problem was also solved.

---

[Olivier Grégoire](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/245806/javascript-syntax-highlighter-for-java#comment482928_245806) noted, that `"\""` and `"\\\""` are not highlighted correctly. I solved this problem also.

---

[Roland Illig](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/245823/214772) suggested to properly parse the java-code. I did not implement this suggestion, because I will first try how far I can come by just using regex.

---

**The code**

```js
//Add listener to highlight-button
document.getElementById('highlightButton').addEventListener('click', highlight);

//Add possibility to use tabs in inputArea
var area = document.getElementById('Input');
area.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 9){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.value = this.value.substring(0,this.selectionStart) + '\t' + this.value.substring(this.selectionEnd);
    }
}

//===============================
//Highlighting-functionality
//===============================

var keywordsColor = '#0033cc';
var controlKeywordsColor = '#009933';
var typesKeywordsColor = '#3399ff';
var stringColor = '#ff3300';
var importColor = '#0033cc';
var commentColor = 'gray';

var text;

var keywords = ['abstract', 'assert', 'const', 'extends', 'false', 'final',
'implements', 'import', 'instanceof', 'interface', 'native', 'new', 'null', 'package',
'private', 'protected', 'public', 'return', 'static', 'strictfp', 'super', 'synchronized',
'System', 'this', 'throw', 'throws', 'transient', 'true', 'volatile'];

var controlKeywords = ['break', 'case', 'catch', 'continue', 'default', 'do', 'else',
'finally', 'for', 'goto', 'if', 'switch', 'try', 'while'];

var typesKeywords = ['boolean', 'byte', 'char', 'double', 'enum', 'float', 'int',
'long', 'short', 'String', 'void'];
var otherKeywords = [];

function highlight() {
    text = document.getElementById('Input').value;
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('&', 'g'), '&amp;');
    text = text.replace(new RegExp('<', 'g'), '&lt;');
    findOtherKeywords();
    highlightKeywords();
    highlightStrings();
    highlightImports();
    highlightSingleLineComments();
    highlightMultiLineComments();

    var arr = text.split("\n");
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = '<code>' + arr[i] + '</code>';
    }

    text = arr.join('\n');
    addStyles();

    var check = document.getElementById('checkbox2');
    if(check.checked) {
        text = '<div style = \'background: LightGray; font-family: monospace;\'>' + text + '</div>';
    }
    document.getElementById('Output').value = text;
    document.getElementById('outputArea').innerHTML = text;

}

function findOtherKeywords() {
    var arr = text.split('\n');
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if(arr[i].startsWith('import')) {
            arr[i] = arr[i].substring(7, arr[i].indexOf(';'));
            var array = arr[i].split('\.');
            for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                typesKeywords.push(array[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}

function highlightKeywords() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < typesKeywords.length; i++) {
        var x = new RegExp(`\\b${typesKeywords[i]}\\b`, 'g');
        var y = '<span class=\'typesKeywordsClass\'>' + typesKeywords[i] + '</span>';
        text = text.replace(x, y);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
        var x = new RegExp(`\\b${keywords[i]}\\b`, 'g');
        var y = '<span class=\'keywordsClass\'>' + keywords[i] + '</span>';
        text = text.replace(x, y);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < controlKeywords.length; i++) {
        var x = new RegExp(`\\b${controlKeywords[i]}\\b`, 'g');
        var y = '<span class=\'controlKeywordsClass\'>' + controlKeywords[i] + '</span>';
        text = text.replace(x, y);
    }

    var x = new RegExp(`\\b(class) `, 'g');
    var y = '<span class=\'keywordsClass\'>' + 'class ' + '</span>';
    text = text.replace(x, y);

}

function highlightStrings() {
    text = text.replace(/"([^"\\]*(\\.[^"\\]*)*)"/,
         '<span class="str" style="color:' + stringColor + '; font-weight:bold;">' 
         + '"$1"' + '</span>');
}

function highlightImports() {
    text = text.replace(/^import(.*?);/g,
         '<span class="str" style="color:' + importColor + '; font-weight:bold;">' 
         + 'import$1;' + '</span>');
}

function highlightSingleLineComments() {
    text = text.replace(/\/\/(.*)/g,
         '<span class="comment" style="color:' + commentColor + '; font-weight:bold;">' 
         + '//$1' + '</span>');
}

function highlightMultiLineComments() {
    text = text.replace(/[ ]*\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\//g, (...match) => {
        let groups = match.pop();
        var str = groups + '';
        var arr = str.split('\n');
        var i = 0;
        var j = 0;
        var test = false;

        for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if(arr[i].includes('*/')) {
                var arr2 = arr[i].split("*/");
                arr2[0] = '<span class="comment" style="color:' + commentColor + '; font-weight:bold;">' 
                    + arr2[0] + '</span>';
                arr[i] = arr2.join('<span class="comment" style="color:' + commentColor + '; font-weight:bold;">' 
                    + '*/' + '</span>')
                break;
            }

            if(arr[i].includes('/*') || test) {
                if(!test) {
                    j = i;
                }
                arr[i] = '<span class="comment" style="color:' + commentColor + '; font-weight:bold;">' 
                    + arr[i] + '</span>';
                test = true;

            } 

        }
        var result = arr.slice(j, i + 1).join('\n');
        return result;
    });

}

function addStyles() {
    var style = '<!-- Style begins here (copy to head) -->\n'
        + '<style> .keywordsClass {color:' + keywordsColor + ';font-weight:bold;}</style>'
        + '<style> .controlKeywordsClass {color:' + controlKeywordsColor + ';font-weight:bold;}</style>'
        + '<style> .typesKeywordsClass {color:' + typesKeywordsColor + ';font-weight:bold;}</style>'
        + '<style>code .comment span {color:' + commentColor + ';}</style>'
        + '<style>code .str span {color:' + stringColor + ';}</style>';

    if(document.getElementById('checkbox1').checked) {
        style = style 
            + '<style> pre{counter-reset: line;}</style>'
            + '<style> code{counter-increment: line;}</style>'
            + '<style> code::before {content: counter(line); display: inline-block; width: 2.5em; border-right: 2px solid gray; padding: 0.2em; margin-right: 0.5em; color: gray;}</style>';
    }

    style = style 
        + '\n<!-- Style ends here -->\n';
 
    text = style
        + '\n<!-- Code begins here -->\n'
        + '\n<pre>\n' 
        + text
        + '\n</pre>\n<!-- Code ends here -->\n';
}
```

```css
body {
    tab-size: 4;
    -moz-tab-size: 4;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    /* Background pattern from Toptal Subtle Patterns */
    background: url('../pictures/extra_clean_paper.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inner {
    tab-size: 4;
    -moz-tab-size: 4;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    background: white;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80%;
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

/* Navigation bar style */
header {
    display: table-row;
    background: #252628;
    height: 40px;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

header ul { 
    background: #252628;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    width: 80%;
    top: 0;
    z-index:9999;

}

header li {
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid LightGray;
    height: 40px;
}

header a {
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: large;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 4px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    width: auto;
    color: LightGray;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

header li:hover {
    background: #688B57;

}

header  li ul {
    display: none;

}

header li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    list-style:none;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: #252628;
    width: auto;
    
}

header ul li ul li{
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  float:none;
  text-align: left;
  border-top: 2px solid LightGray;
  border-right: none;
}

.icon {
    padding-right: 4px;
    line-height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

/* Main */
main {
    display: table-row;
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;

}

/* Footer */
footer {
    display: table-row;
    background: #252628;
    min-height: 60px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    float: right;
    bottom: 0;
    position: relative;
}

footer ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

footer ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 40px;
    line-height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    justify-content:center;
}

footer ul li a  {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: LightGray;
}

/* Other */
#code {
    background: LightGray;
    font-family: monospace;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

.caption {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.icons {
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: right;

}

.right {
    float: right; 
    width: 40px;

}

.rightLink {
    width: 40px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    font-family: "Courier";
    font-style: italic;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #252628;
}

.list > li {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.input {
    width: 80%;
    border: 2px solid #252628;
    padding: 20px;
    background: LightGray;
}

.formText {
    border: 1px solid #252628;
    box-shadow: none;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    resize: none; 
    width: 100%; 
    position: relative;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 16px;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.formText:focus {
    border:1px solid green;
}

figure {
    text-align: center;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}

figure img {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <!-- Head -->
    <head>
        <script>
            window.onerror=function(msg, url, linenumber) {
                alert('Error message: ' + msg + '\nURL: ' + url + '\nLine Number: ' + linenumber);
                return true;
            }
        </script>
        <meta charset='utf-8'>
        <title>Highlighting</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/style.css'>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class='inner'>
            <!-- Navigation bar -->
            <header>
                <div class='nav'>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href='../index.html'><img class='icon' src='../pictures/iconmonstr-home-7-24.png' alt=''/>Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href='tools.html'><img class='icon' src='../pictures/iconmonstr-wrench-2-24.png' alt=''/>Tools</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href='highlighting.html'>Highlighting</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href='about.html'><img class='icon' src='../pictures/iconmonstr-user-6-24.png' alt=''/>About</a></li>
                        <li><a href='contact.html'><img class='icon' src='../pictures/iconmonstr-email-2-24.png' alt=''/>Contact</a></li>
                      
                    </ul> 

                </div>
            </header>

            <main>
                <div style='margin:30px; margin-top: 50px'>
                    <h2>HTML syntax-highlighting for Java</h2>

                    <!-- Left column -->
                    <div class='column'>

                        <!-- Input Area -->
                        <h4>Input:</h4>
                        <div>
                            <textarea id='Input' rows='8' style='resize: none; background: LightGray; position: relative; width: 80%;'></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <form>
                            <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox1' name='checkbox1' value='numbers'>
                            <label for='checkbox1'>Include line numbers</label><br>
                            <input type='checkbox' id='checkbox2' name='checkbox2' value='background'>
                            <label for='checkbox2'>Include background-color</label>
                        </form>  
                        <br><br>
                        <button type='button' id='highlightButton'>Highlight</button> 

                        <!-- Output Area -->
                        <h4>Output:</h4>
                        <div>
                            <textarea id='Output' rows='8' style='resize: none; background: LightGray; position: relative; width: 80%;'></textarea>
                        </div>  

                    </div>

                    <!-- Right Column -->
                    <div class='column'>
                        <h4>Preview</h4>
                        <div id='outputArea' style='overflow-y:auto; overflow-x:auto; height: 690px'></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>

            <footer>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href='../index.html'>Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href='about.html'>About</a></li>
                    <li><a href='license.html'>License</a></li>
                    <li><a href='impressum.html'>Impressum</a></li>
                    <li><a href='datenschutz.html'>Datenschutz</a></li>
                </ul> 
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script src='../javascript/highlightSyntax.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've checked the syntactic validity of the javascript-code with [this](https://esprima.org/demo/validate.html) tool and the html/css-code with [this](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) one.

**Example**

If you want to test the code, you can use the following snippet:

```java
import java.time.LocalDate; 

public class Person {
    //Local variable for dateOfBirth
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;    

    public Person(int year, int month, int day) {
        //See API also: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html
        dateOfBirth = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
        //Keywords (e.g. int) are not highlighted in comments and strings
        System.out.println("Hello (int)");
    }

    /*
     * Getter "DateOfBirth"
     */
    public LocalDate getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

**Question**

All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm glad to see you incorporated much of the feedback from the answers to your previous post. I see you added the colors into CSS, but dynamically. I believe those styles for the colors could exist with the static CSS. Actually the whole `addStyles()` function could likely be eliminated using conditional classes (e.g. if checkbox1 is checked, then add an extra class name to the element with id `outputArea` and add those styles when the class is applied - e.g.

```
#outputArea.showLineNums pre{
    counter-reset: line;
}
#outputArea.showLineNums code{
    counter-increment: line;
}
#outputArea.showLineNums code::before {
    content: counter(line); 
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 2.5em; 
    border-right: 2px solid gray; 
    padding: 0.2em;
    margin-right: 0.5em; 
    color: gray;
}
```

---

I see there is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in `highlightMultiLineComments()` as well as the `let` keyword. Those are  features of [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) (A.K.A. ES-6) and there are some others that could be used - e.g. [`for...of` loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) could really simplify the syntax of `for` loops (though performance may suffer because they use iterators). Many modern JS programmers avoid using the `var` keyword unless a global variable is needed (which many programmers hold is bad practice anyway). A common recommendation is to use `const` as a default and then use `let` when you determine a value can be re-assigned (e.g. loop variables). For more information about ES-6 see [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_2015_support_in_Mozilla#Standard_library) (including [browser support](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)) as well as http://es6-features.org/

The last two lines of that arrow function assigns and returns a single-use variable (i.e. `result`). Some may argue that the extra variable allocates extra memory though for a small case like this it is likely not going to make much of a difference. This might be something a linter would catch. If you haven't already done so, you may want to start using a linter - e.g. [esLint](https://eslint.org/), [jsLint](https://jslint.com/).

---

The first line adds an event listener to the element with id `highlightButton` using `addEventListener()`. Then after that the `onkeydown` property is set on the element with id `Input`. The `keydown` event listener could be set using `addEventListener()`, which would allow multiple listeners to be added if necessary.

---

Values in variables like `keywordsColor` don't appear to change so those could be put in constants - and a common convention is to use `ALL_CAPS` so anyone reading the code can tell the value doesn't change, and declare them at the top of your code (or in a separate file/[module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules)):

```
const KEYWORDS_COLOR = '#0033cc';
const CONTROL_KEYWORDS_COLOR = '#009933';

const KEYWORDS = Object.freeze(['abstract', 'assert', ...]);
```

Then if you need to modify those values they can be found easily. If you want to ensure that a constant can't be modified (e.g. an array can't be modified via `.push()`)  the value can be wrapped in [`Object.freeze()`].

---

The name of the checkboxes could be improved - e.g. instead of `checkbox1` and `checkbox2`, names like `includeLineNums` and `includeBGcolor` would be more descriptive and not much longer.

---

The CSS has these padding rules under `header a`:

> ```
> padding: 4px;
> padding-left: 10px;
> padding-right: 10px;
> ```

Those can be combined into a single rule:

```
padding: 4px 10px
```

The same applies to the ruleset for `.formText`:

> ```
> padding-top: 2px;
> padding-bottom: 2px;
> ```

Can be combined to:

```
padding: 2px 0;
```

Comment: Nice answer. This is the first time I've seen ES6 be called ES-6.

Answer (score 3):

> [Mast](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/245816) mentioned that it is not possible to have html-tags in for example comments, without destroying the formatting.
>
> I've solved this problem by replacing `&` and `<`:
>
> ```
> text = text.replace(new RegExp("&", "g"), "&amp;");
> text = text.replace(new RegExp("<", "g"), "&lt;");
> ```

You can safely escape everything [by using `Option`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22706073). I would prefer this as everything gets escaped correctly rather than leaving it to chance.

```
text = new Option(text).innerHTML;
```